# JSON JQUERY Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to programming.  I am trying to display JSON data into an HTML file using JQuery. I am getting an error of `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefinedresumeBuilder.js:147 education.displayresumeBuilder.js:178 (anonymous function)` in my console, and I'm not sure why.  Any light you can shed on this error would be much appreciated!

Here is my resumeBuilder.js file:

```
var eduction = {
    "schools": [
        {
            "name": "McGill University",
            "location": "Montreal, Quebec, Canada",
            "degree": "Master of Arts",
            "major": "Second Language Education",
            "url": "mcgill.ca"
        }
    ],
    "onlineCourses": [
        {
            "title": "Full Stack Web Development Course",
            "school": "Bloc.io",
            "url": "bloc.io"
        }
    ]
};

education.display = function() {
    if(education.schools.length > 0 || education.onlineCourses.length > 0) {
        for(i in education.schools) {
            $("#education").append(HTMLschoolStart);

            var formattedSchoolName = HTMLschoolName.replace("%data%",      education.schools[i].name).replace("#", education.schools[i].url);
            var formattedSchoolDegree = HTMLschoolDegree.replace("%data%",     education.schools[i].degree);
            var formattedSchoolLocation = HTMLschoolLocation.replace("%data%", education.schools[i].location);
            var formattedSchoolMajor = HTMLschoolMajor.replace("%data%", education.schools[i].major);

            $(".education-entry:last").append(formattedSchoolName + formattedSchoolDegree);
            $(".education-entry:last").append(formattedSchoolLocation);
            $(".education-entry:last").append(formattedSchoolMajor);
        }

        if(education.onlineCourses.length > 0) {
            $("#education").append(HTMLonlineClasses);
            for(i in education.onlineCourses) {
                $("#education").append(HTMLschoolStart);
                var formattedOnlineTitle = HTMLonlineTitle.replace("%data%", education.onlineCourses[i].title).replace("#", education.onlineCourses[i].url);
                var formattedOnlineSchool = HTMLonlineSchool.replace("%data%", education.onlineCourses[i].school);
                var formattedOnlineURL = HTMLonlineURL.replace("%data%", education.onlineCourses[i].url).replace("#", education.onlineCourses[i].url);

                $(".education-entry:last").append(formattedOnlineTitle);
                $(".education-entry:last").append(formattedOnlineSchool);
                $(".education-entry:last").append(formattedOnlineURL);
            }
        }
    }
}

education.display();
```

Here is my helper.js file:

```
var HTMLschoolStart = '<div class="education-entry"></div>';
var HTMLschoolName = '<a href="#">%data%';
var HTMLschoolDegree = ' -- %data%</a>';
var HTMLschoolLocation = '<div class="location-text">%data%</div>';
var HTMLschoolMajor = '<em><br>Major: %data%</em>';

var HTMLonlineClasses = '<h3>Online Classes</h3>';
var HTMLonlineTitle = '<a href="#">%data%';
var HTMLonlineSchool = ' - %data%</a>';
var HTMLonlineURL = '<br><a href="#">%data%</a>';
```

Comment: Can you tell us in this code which line is `:178 `?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a typo in your first JSON object.

`var eduction = {`

Should have an "a" in it.

Answer (score 1):

you misspelt education - eduction line 1

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your `var eduction = {` => `var education = {`

You also might want to change:

```
var HTMLonlineClasses = '<h3>Online Classes</h3>';
```

to match the variable you are comparing in your javascript.

```
education.onlineCourses

var HTMLonlineCourses = '<h3>Online Courses</h3>';
```

So in the future it would be easier to find and update references to that variable